# Why does `window.location.search` not match `window.location`'s `search` field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I have logged out the following `window.location` in my React app (using Google Chrome):

```
{
    "ancestorOrigins": {},
    "href": "http://localhost:3000/my-path?foo=bar",
    "origin": "http://localhost:3000",
    "protocol": "http:",
    "host": "localhost:3000",
    "hostname": "localhost",
    "port": "3000",
    "pathname": "/my-path",
    "search": "?foo=bar",
    "hash": ""
}
```

However, logging out `window.location.search` in the console (on the next line) shows that it's an empty string: `""`. This seems to contradict the `search` field on the `window.location` object. Here are my logs:

```
console.log("location", window.location); // search: "?foo=bar"
console.log("search", window.location.search); // ""
```

Furthermore, both (a) a simple 1 second timeout inside a `React.useEffect` and (b) a page reload each result in the `window.location.search` logging out to be `"?foo=bar"` as expected.

I expected `window.location.search` to match the `search` field on the `window.location` object, but it doesn't. I suspect some sort of race condition, but I don't understand the mismatch between `window.location` and `window.location.search`

Comment: You’re probably not seeing window.location as it was when the console.log command ran.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Answer (score 0):

As @james pointed out in the comments, it turns out that my first `console.log` was referencing the *stored* `window.location` object, which *initially* had an empty `search` field, but later was updated with a populated `search` field. The log in the dev tools UI was simply updated to reflect this change.

This is corroborated by another log I added as a test:

```
// includes `"search":""`
console.log("stringified", JSON.stringify(window.location));
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync) for more details.